# Angular 2 Material change md-radio-button color

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I want to change the default color of the md-radio-button to blue. Is there any way to override the current color?

https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview

I tried (solution i found here):

```
.my-radio md-radio-button , md-radio-button.md-checked ._md-on{
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
}
```

however this isnt working.

Comment: Try `<md-radio-button color="..."></md-radio-button>`

Comment: Pak, I don't suggest to override the current properties set. You can create a custom theme with your desire colors: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Answer (score 1):

You can set the style in the component's CSS file:

```
/deep/ .mat-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-outer-circle {
    border-color: DodgerBlue;
}

/deep/ .mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle {
    background-color: DodgerBlue;
}
```

If you want to apply it for whole application, then put the css in root component's css.